# Can I check out/create a tag with certain commits left out?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-tag

I want to create a tag that leaves out certain commits. So when creating the tag, I choose which commits to add (or which to omit). This would enable me to deploy a hot fix and leave out older (and newer) commits.

The same could be achieved by using branches, but I don't want to make one branch per environment (dev, test, staging, prod). So if I could create all tags in 1 branch, I could deploy only prod tags to prod and HEAD to the rest (dev, test, staging).

Maybe something with git-notes?

(Cherry picking to a tag?)

Comment: Why do you not want to make one branch per environment?  That's a perfect application for branches...

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work deploying, merging, bug fixing (and searching). Prod doesn't need a branch. There's no changes on prod, just a bunch o' files. A branch seems strange for that. Same on staging (and test too actually). Branches just to merge and tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Git, tags are used to identify a single commit, and branches are used to identify a sequence of commits.  You can create a new branch by picking the desired commits from the different branches (or environments as you call them).  Then deploy the new branch to prod and HEAD to the rest (dev, test, staging).  However, you may want to consider using a different workflow that is more accommadating.

See http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 1):

As said, in git tags are used to identify a single commit. A single commit identifies the state of a the whole repository and specific point in time, so what you're asking cannot be done in git.

What can be done is, like said, is to create a new branch where you can cherry-pick the stuff you want and then tag that.

I don't understand your comment that prod doesn't need a branch. It does, we've done it that way for a long time, even with other VCS software than git (even if selective tagging/labeling has been supported, so the separation is clear). It is common practice to create a new branch for a production release, either one for each release or one production branch containing all prod releases.

Comment: It shouldn't be common practice to create a new branch (!!) for a production release. I release every 2 weeks. I don't want 25 new branches per year! That's why tags exist: releases. A branch should be a new feature that can be developed separate from bug fixes and normal development.

Comment: My 'prod needs no branch' comment means prod is ust a collection of files. Staging for prod happens on pre-prod/staging. I don't want to have to log in on prod. Ever. Definitely not to check out a new release. I push to prod, which checks out master, not a custom branch every release. I have to be able to control it from dev or test. How would you release to prod? Log in there and check out the new branch?

Comment: @Rudie we don't release from VCS, we execute builds on build server which push binary artifacts with specific versions to Nexus. The deployment mechanism takes specific versions from Nexus. My opinion is that releases are best not to done from VCS. Branches should not affect what you actually release - you usually release packaged binary artifacts, not code. I come from background where release artifacts are compiled, but I don't see how that couldn't apply for scripting language stuff, too.

Comment: Branches are not meant to be long-lived, usually. So you don't have 25 active branches, you have for the duration of year total of 25 branches but only 2-3 are worked on max at any time.

Comment: But of course, all of this is my opinion and you don't have to agree with me. This is just how I see the stuff :)

Comment: As a side note, I've worked with projects that have 10-100 simultanious developers, some working on production release fixes, some on new features. This might affect the way I see things. To keep work from getting messed up, separate branches have been a must.